# Change Has Children to Has GrandChildren in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Here is an except of javascript.

```
    function showContent(layer, animate) {

        $("#background").show();
        $("footer").hide();
        $("#announcement").hide();

        $("#content").html($("#" + layer + "_html").comments());

        $("nav").children().each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr("id").search(layer) == -1) {
                $(this).addClass("inactive");
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("inactive");
            }
        });

        if (animate == true) {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("nav").offset().top - 16 - 40}, 200, "swing");
        }

        // setUpHover();

        setupFullScreen();
        setupImageViewers();
        setupHovers();

        // Load analytics tracking
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#tracker").attr("src", "/track/" + layer + "/")
        }, 500);

        window.location.hash = layer;
    }

    // Set up the on click functions for the different menus
    $("nav").children().click(function() {
        showContent($(this).attr("id").split("_")[1], true);
    });
```

Here is an excerpt of html:

http://pastie.org/2929494

Now here's my question. With that js and html it does what it is suppose to. However when I add a needed div  inside the nav as such it breaks:

http://pastie.org/2929497

I imagine the problem is in the original js above, there are two lines about ("nav").children and imagine with my new code they are actually now grandchildren or such. So most likely need to make minor adjustments to both of those lines, but not sure to what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace `children` with `find`.

Comment: That's so funny, I had just tried that before your comment based on my findings here: http://www.hackosis.com/jquery-descendants-and-children/ however it did not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the line you're asking about is :

```
$("nav").children().click(function() {
```

You could do:

```
$("nav").children().children().click(function() {
```

to get the "grand children".  However, I would probably use a class instead to make this a bit more resilient.

```
$("nav").find(".navLink").click(function() {
```

Where `navLink` is a class that you add to each of the elements which you want to be clickable.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work either. That is adding the extra .children() to both places where it currently says: $("nav").children().click(function() {

Comment: Is there someway to do: $("nav > .needed").children().click(function() { kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, that should work as well.  If you could post a working example people may be able to help a bit better.  My suggestions as well as the one you just posted should work just fine unless there's something else wrong.  Hard to say when I can't run the code.

Comment: Oh actually it did work. The find option from the other poster didn't but the double .children did. Was a typo before. Thanks!